# Error inserting IP address into mysql

Tags: python, mysql, ip

I have tried many times with different codes to insert an ip address in mysql int unsigned field, any pointers please, i have looked at all the examples on google, nothing helps

here is my code

```
    icecast_source_ip = "INET_ATON('" + icecast_source_ip  +"')"
    print icecast_source_ip
    cnx = mysql.connector.connect(host=mysql_remote_host,
                                  user=mysql_remote_host_user, 
                                  password=mysql_remote_host_password,
                                  database=mysql_remote_host_database)
    cursor = cnx.cursor()
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO icecast_monitor.status_log  
                     (website_online, icecast_source_online, icecast_source_ip,
                      icecast_no_listeners, centerpoint_online, centerpoint_connection,
                      horsleypark_online, horsleypark_connection, system_ok)
                    VALUES ('" + website_online + "','"
                            + icecast_source_online + "','"
                            + icecast_source_ip + "','"
                            + icecast_no_listeners + "','"
                            + centerpoint_online + "','"
                            + centerpoint_connection + "','"
                            + horsleypark_online + "','"
                            + horsleypark_connection + "','"
                            + system_ok +   "')
                   ")
    print 'Data inserted into Database'
    cnx.commit()
    cursor.close()
    cnx.close()
```

and the error that i get

> Unexpected error 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax;
>   check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the
>   right syntax to use near
>   '60.241.175.9')','19','True','Main','True','Main','False')' at line 1

Comment: You're not quoting your values. Better to use prepared statements anyway.

Comment: please see update

Comment: Please read [Preventing SQL injections in Python](https://blog.sqreen.io/preventing-sql-injections-in-python/)!

Comment: Now you're quoting too many values. The IP one doesn't need quotes. Do yourself a favor: prepared statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in a comment you are not quoting the values, thus strings such as the IP address do not have the required surrounding single quotes in the final SQL query.

The proper, and safe, way is to use parameterised queries. You do not need to worry about quoting, nor do you need to worry about SQL injection vulnerabilities that may occur when manually constructing query strings with string operations. For your example you could do this:

```
query = """INSERT INTO icecast_monitor.status_log
            (website_online, icecast_source_online, icecast_source_ip,
             icecast_no_listeners, centerpoint_online, centerpoint_connection,
             horsleypark_online, horsleypark_connection, system_ok)
           VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"""

cursor.execute(query, (website_online, icecast_source_online, icecast_source_ip, icecast_no_listeners, centerpoint_online, centerpoint_connection, horsleypark_online, horsleypark_connection, system_ok))
```

This uses the placeholder `%s` to indicate where the parameters should be inserted, and then `cursor.excute()` inserts the parameters in the second argument with the proper quoting into the query before sending it off for execution.

Comment: thanks, i get the following Unexpected error 1366 (HY000): Incorrect integer value: 'INET_ATON('60.241.175.9')' for column 'icecast_source_ip' at row 1

Comment: @Ossama: pass in the IP address as a string but call the function within the query: `VALUES (%s, %s, INET_ATON(%s), %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"""` and set `icecast_source_ip = '60.241.175.9'`.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is with value of variable `icecast_source_ip`.
You already have single quotes surrounding the soure ip value variable.

```
icecast_source_ip = "INET_ATON('" + icecast_source_ip  +"')"
```

But when using it in the query, you again surrounded the generated string with quotes. Resulting query became like the following:

```
// + "','" + icecast_source_ip + "','"
 + "','"+ INET_ATON(' + 60.241.175.9 + ') + "','"
```

For readability, the string replacement looked like this:

```
 + "','INET_ATON('60.241.175.9')','"
```

And hence the actual ip address value `60.241.175.9` was out of quotes and sql engine was trying to recognize it as identifier but failed as it is in wrong format and hence is a syntax error.

Please use prepared statements to overcome such issues.